# How to color selected item of ListView on android at onListItemClick method

Tags: java, android, listview

I know that familiar question exist my is a little different.
I'm implementing ListView on android. 
This method should color item when it clicked.

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, longid) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Language lng = lng.get(position);
        l.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

My problem is that when i click on item some other items are get colored to.
why is that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is that happens?

Its happen because of [ListView's recycling mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works).

> And is there a difference between l.getChildAt(position) to view v
>   itself ?

No.

---

To solve your problem, i suggest you to use a [Selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) to change rows color depending on state.

eg:

1) Create a selector xml file: *listview_selector.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_focused" />

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_pressed" />

    </selector>
```

2) Add the selector to your ListView:

```
<ListView
   ...
   android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
/>
```

Comment: It should be '@drawable' instead of '@color' when applying in the ListView, if you created the file listview_selector.xml in drawable folder. Worked like a charm, thanks.

Comment: @LucasEduardo You're welcome! it was a typo, thanks... i've edited my answer.